# Control App by Keyboard

Tags: android, events, keyboard

I develope an Android app. 
I want when user press a key on keyboard (connecting by bluetooth or cable), my app do a specific task.
Example: When user press [M] key, the app will show the menu.

How can I do it?
I means how my app (not a view) listen keyboard?

Comment: Did you try anything before posting? [This](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html) was easy to find. Does it work?

Comment: I've tried KeyEvent.Callback as your suggestion and still trying.
This is the first time I work with hard keyboard, I try to get more approachings to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Activity.dispatchKeyEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)) method.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can override onKeyDown/Up of Activity to listen any key is pressed.